# Recursion returning all matching answers

Tags: java, recursion, return

Hello I am using recursion as show below.

```
public static int match(int[][] mat , int count)
    {

        boolean isComplete = true;
        for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<mat[i].length;j++)
            {
                if(mat[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    isComplete = false;
                    count++;
                    ArrayList<int[][]> mMats =  getMats(mat, i, j);
                    for(int k=0;k<mMats.size();k++)
                    {
                        match(mMats.get(k), count);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if(isComplete)
        {
            System.out.println(count);
            return count;

        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

What i want to achieve is if we reach at isComplete block it should return me that particular count. I don't want other counts, right now fuction returning many counts how I can solve this. thanks.

Comment: The function is printing multiple counts because `if(isComplete)` can be called every time the function is run recursively. If you only want the total count you could print the return value from wherever you call the match function for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could stop iterating if the recursive call returns something else than `0`. i.e., when the first match is found:

```
...
for(int k=0;k<mMats.size();k++) {
    int ret = match(mMats.get(k), count);
    if(ret != 0)
        return ret;
}
...
```

Comment: for work around i have taken 0 actually any number can be given at place of 0.

Comment: @Crazy You're returning a count, which I assume is expected to be positive. So you could return -1 instead of 0 and check for that.